# ArrayList adding element to 3rd layer

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm looping through an arraylist and trying to add each of the answers I get from                         ai.get(k).add(Cent.get(k).get(m)-Cent.get(k).get(l)); into the respective arraylist of arraylist of arraylist. For every three elements it should add the following elements to a new arraylist. There are 12 elements in this dataset so it should look like [[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]],[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[]]]

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> ai = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
        // Creates arrays based on number of centroids
        for (int k = 0; k < numCen; k++) {
            ai.add(new ArrayList(k));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numCen; i++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < dim; k++) {
            ai.get(i).add(new ArrayList(k));
            //ai.add(new ArrayList(i));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(ai);     


        // Gets all of the centroids
            for (int k = 0; k < numCen; k++) {
                // Gets the centroid itself
                for (int m = 0; m < Cent.size() + 1; m++) {
                    // Gets all the elements in array
                    for (int l = 0; l < Cent.size() + 1; l++) {
                        // Skips over the element being subtracted so you never get 0
                        if(Cent.get(k).get(m) == Cent.get(k).get(l)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        //Places all the elements in ai
                        ai.get(k).add(Cent.get(k).get(m)-Cent.get(k).get(l));
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(ai);
        }
```

Here is my current output:

> [[[], [], [], [], -0.4861111111108659, 0.18691148775888072,
>   0.18055555555552283, 0.4861111111108659, 
>   0.6730225988697466, 0.6666666666663887, -0.18691148775888072, -0.6730225988697466, 
>   -0.006355932203357881, -0.18055555555552283, -0.6666666666663887, 0.006355932203357881], [[], [], [],  [], 0.027777777777828083, -0.2504708097928492, -0.2638888888887171, -0.027777777777828083, 
>   -0.2782485875706773, -0.29166666666654517, 0.2504708097928492, 0.2782485875706773, 
>   -0.013418079095867896, 0.2638888888887171, 0.29166666666654517, 0.013418079095867896], [[], [], [], [],  -0.40277777777757906, 0.15442561205268038, 0.1805555555555111, 0.40277777777757906, 0.5572033898302594, 
>   0.5833333333330901, -0.15442561205268038, -0.5572033898302594, 0.02612994350283071, -0.1805555555555111, 
>   -0.5833333333330901, -0.02612994350283071]]

Expected output:

```
[[[-0.4861111111108659, 0.18691148775888072, 0.18055555555552283], 
[0.4861111111108659, 0.6730225988697466, 0.6666666666663887], 
[-0.18691148775888072, -0.6730225988697466, -0.006355932203357881], 
[-0.18055555555552283, -0.6666666666663887, 0.006355932203357881]], 
[[0.027777777777828083, -0.2504708097928492, -0.2638888888887171], 
[-0.027777777777828083, -0.2782485875706773, -0.29166666666654517], 
[0.2504708097928492, 0.2782485875706773, -0.013418079095867896], 
[0.2638888888887171, 0.29166666666654517, 0.013418079095867896]], [[ 
-0.40277777777757906, 0.15442561205268038, 0.1805555555555111], 
[0.40277777777757906, 0.5572033898302594, 0.5833333333330901], 
[-0.15442561205268038, -0.5572033898302594, 0.02612994350283071], 
[-0.1805555555555111, -0.5833333333330901, -0.02612994350283071]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You add a 3rd layer. At the moment you have only two.

1. `List<Integer>` could store `[1,2]`
2. `List<List<Integer>>` can store `[[1,2],[3,4]]`, this is what you have now
3. `List<List<List<Integer>>>` could store `[ [[1,2],[3,4]] , [[5,6],[7,8]] ]`

The number of `List<>`s packed inside each other is the number of layers (or dimensions, that is a common name).
Of course any of the `List`s can be empty, `[]`.

---

Oh, well, yes.
So your inner `ArrayList` contains generic `Object`-s, which you happen to fill up with `ArrayList`s, but it remains hard to access them, which you would do as:

```
((ArrayList)ai.get(firstIndex).get(secondIndex)).get/set(thirdIndex)
```

This is what is not happening in your code, so I am a bit puzzled why you would have anything on the third level. That is something what you do not show at all.

Anyway, you should really switch to a "more typed" approach, and have

```
List<List<List<Float>>> ai=new ArrayList<>();
```

at the beginning.

Comment: I have a third layer already. This is the empty arraylist. [[[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []], [[], [], [], []]]. I need help putting the elements in them.